# Bash loop through folders and rename file

Tags: bash

Imagine a folder called `parent-folder` with the following.  The parent contains children and each child contains a style.css file.  I need a bash script that renames each CSS file to `_style.scss`.  Also, I need to prepend `@import 'glue1';` to each of the stylesheets.

```
parent-folder
    child-folder
      style.css
    child-folder
      style.css
    child-folder
      style.css
```

This is what I have put together.  I'm struggling to understand this due to my lack of knowledge in bash.  I find it really hard to write scripts.

```
for file in */**; do
    echo "@import 'glue1';"|cat - $file > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out $file
    echo ${file/%.css/.scss}
done;
```

What that script does when called from `parent-folder`:

1. loop through each and every sub directory
2. Prepend `@import 'glue1';` to each css file by creating a temp file.
3. Echo out the new file route replacing `.css` with `.scss`

My question is...

What is [this] `${file/%.css/.scss}` technique called and how do I prepend an `_` (underscore) in front of the filename?

Comment: Read the man page for `find`: it is meant for these kind of tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${file/%.css/.scss}` is called [*parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). You are replacing the `.css` suffix with a `.scss` suffix. You could accomplish your renaming using a combination of parameter expansion and some other functions like so:

```
mv $file $(dirname $file)/_$(basename ${file/%.css/.scss})
```

However, this seems like overkill. If you know all your files need to be renamed `_style.scss` regardless of what they were originally called, then you can just do:

```
mv $file $(dirname $file)/_style.scss
```

**Simpler:**

In fact, if you only want to change files called `style.css` (your current script changes every file in every subdirectory), and you know they're all already called `style.css`, then this would be a simpler way, which only iterates through each subdirectory of your current directory (instead of all the files within those subdirectories):

```
for dir in */; do
  echo "@import 'glue1';" | cat - "${dir}"style.css > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out "${dir}"_style.scss
done
```

Or write to a file, then remove the old one (this looks more canonical to me):

```
for dir in */; do
  echo "@import 'glue1';" >"${dir}"_style.scss
  cat "${dir}"style.scss >>"${dir}"_style.scss
  rm "${dir}"style.scss
done
```

Comment: `${dir}` should be surrounded by double quotes to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Comment: Absolutely true and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `find` and `dirname` commands for renaming and `sed` for prepending the line to file contents:

```
for i in `find . -name 'style.css'`; do
    sed -i '1s;^;@import '"'"'glue1'"'"'\;\n;' $i;
    mv $i "`dirname $i`/_style.scss";
done
```

If you'll need to work with file names other than `style.css`, you may also need `basename` command which extracts the file name only, so it is somewhat opposite to `dirname`.

There is also `rename` command which replaces patterns in file names, but it seems to be an overcomplication for your case.